# Sending big file by webservice and OOM exception

Tags: c#, file, web-services, out-of-memory

I have webservice, with method:

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] GetFile(string FName)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs1 = null;
                fs1 = System.IO.File.Open(FName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] b1 = new byte[fs1.Length];
    fs1.Read(b1, 0, (int)fs1.Length);
    fs1.Close();
    return b1; 
}
```

and it works with small file like 1mb, but when it comes to photoshop's  file (about 1,5gb)  I get:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

on this line:

```
Byte[] img = new Byte[fs.Length];
```

The idea is I have winforms application which get this file and saving it on local disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on where the exception is being thrown.  Most likely what is happening is that a file that size is going into the Large Object Heap (LOH) and the memory fragmentation is causing that problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2006/04/18/large-object-heap.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/webtopics/archive/2009/05/22/Troubleshooting-System.OutOfMemoryExceptions-in-ASP.NET.aspx

Link to a similiar SO question:
[How do I get .NET to garbage collect aggressively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860917/how-do-i-get-c-to-garbage-collect-aggressively/2860930#2860930)